# What does "扎し魔神" mean in this epiphet?

Tags: translation, kanji

What does "扎し魔神" mean in this epiphet?

[image: かつて魔法石を統ベる者と呼ば扎し魔神]

I think it says "かつて魔法石を統ベる者と呼ば扎し魔神", but I'm not sure because the font has strange kerning...

So, I'm having:

"かつて魔法石を統ベる者" == "Former Magic Stone Lord"

"と呼ば扎し魔神" == "And also called [扎し] Majin/Magic God/Demon God/Etc."

But I'm not sure if "扎し魔神" is a compound word or something...

So, can you help me out?

**What is "扎し魔神" in the context of that epiphet?**

Comment: This is `呼ばれし魔神`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that font being hard to read if you don't understand everything yet.

That is not 「扎し」 but 「れし」part of 「呼ばれし」, "to be called".

「かつて」 can be translated to "ex-", but it also means "once" or "long ago", for cases where someone is praising another or when talking about a title that doesn't necessarily have an "ex-" or is actually still continuing into the present, which would be the case here.

Thus

かつて魔法石を統ベる者と呼ばれし魔神 = The demon god who long ago was called he who governs magic stones.

Comment: And し here is a 連体形 (attributive form) of the [archaic auxiliary verb き](http://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009002.htm), which forms the past tense and corresponds to た in modern Japanese.